# Error CS1941 al ejecutar join que combina varios campos

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. actualmente estoy teniendo un error al tratar de ejecutar un join que combina varios campos. Este es el código:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
    public List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes, 
        string? Obra, string? Almacen) 
    {
        var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
        var q = from a in t
                where
                (   
                    (
                        Obra == null
                        ||
                        Obra == ""
                        ||
                        Obra == a.Obra
                    )
                    &&
                    (
                        Almacen == null
                        ||
                        Almacen == ""
                        ||
                        Almacen == a.nom_bodega
                    )
                )
                //join con la tabla obtenida en GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = a.fecha,
                    Equipo = a.equipo,
                    Salida = a.numero,
                    Bodega = a.bodega,
                    Cantidad = a.cantidad
                }
                equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.equipo,
                    Salida = b1.salida,
                    Bodega = b1.bodega,
                    Cantidad = b1.cantidad
                }
                into GrupoB
                //esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby
                    a.Obra,
                    a.equipo,
                    a.fecha
                select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                {
                    equipo = a.equipo,
                    bodega = a.bodega,
                    nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                    cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                    familia = a.familia,
                    fecha = a.fecha,
                    codigo = a.codigo,
                    descripcion = a.descripcion,
                    tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                    tipo = a.tipo,
                    numero = a.numero,
                    cantidad = a.cantidad,
                    costo = a.costo,
                    total_costo = a.total_costo,
                    destino = a.destino,
                    horometro = a.horometro,
                    adicional = a.adicional,
                    horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                    empresa = a.empresa,
                    FechaInsert = a.FechaInsert,
                    Obra = a.Obra,
                    //Poner la función para la operacion y la validacion para el estado.
                    Operacion = a.Operacion,
                    Estado = a.Estado,
                };
        return q.ToList();
    }
```

Lo primero que hice fue validar los tipos de datos que estoy comparando en el join. para ello fui a los modelos de las tablas que se estan utilizando en dicho join. Estas son:

GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros

```
public class TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? Equipo { get; set; }
    public int Salida { get; set; }
    public int Bodega { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Luego valido el modelo de GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras

```
public class TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
{
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? nom_bodega { get; set; }
    public int cod_familia { get; set; }
    public string? familia { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public string? codigo { get; set; }
    public string? descripcion { get; set; }
    public string? tipo_salida { get; set; }
    public string? tipo { get; set; }
    public int numero { get; set; }
    public decimal cantidad { get; set; }
    public SqlMoney costo { get; set; }
    public SqlMoney total_costo { get; set; }
    public string? destino { get; set; }
    public string? horometro { get; set; }
    public string? adicional { get; set; }
    public string? horometro_ingresado { get; set; }
    public string? empresa { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
    public string? Obra { get; set; }
    public string? Operacion { get; set; }
    public string? Estado { get; set; }
    
}
```

comienzo a validar uno a uno para identificar si en una tabla tengo un tipo de dato y en la otra otro tipo, ya que el error que me aparece me esta sugiriendo esta posibilidad. Este es el error que me aparece:

```
Error   CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.
```

La validación permite confirmar lo siguiente:

```
a.fecha y b1.fecha son ambos tipo DateTime
a.equipo y b1.equipo son ambos tipo string
a.numero y b1.salida son ambos tipo int
a.bodega y b1.bodega son ambos tipo int
a.cantidad y b1.cantidad son ambos del tipo decimal
```

Luego de realizar esta validación, no puedo identificar el error.
Agradecemos a todos su ayuda con recomendaciones.

Comment: Una sugerencia que me dio un maestro en `ASP.net Core` y `Microsoft MVP` hace muchos años fue: "Cuando tengas joins muy complejos y cuya función sea `read-only` para mostrar datos solamente, es mejor crear una Vista en SQL Server y mappear esa vista con una clase que tenga todos esos atributos". Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradecemos a Yussef por su respuesta, la cual nos ayudo para identificar los inconvenientes a corregir. Esta fue la forma, como corregimos la falla:

Error 1:

```
join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros on new
```

Corrección 1:

```
    join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new
```

Conculisión 1:
No habíamos asignado los parámetros obligatorios al método GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros

Error 2:

```
public class TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? Equipo { get; set; }
    public int Salida { get; set; }
    public int Bodega { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Corrección 2:

```
public record TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? Equipo { get; set; }
    public int Salida { get; set; }
    public int Bodega { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Conclusión 2:

Se hace el cambio de estructura class por record ya que class no permite que se de el join.

Error 3:

```
equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.equipo,
                    Salida = b1.salida,
                    Bodega = b1.bodega,
                    Cantidad = b1.cantidad / 2
                }
```

Corrección 3:

```
equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.Equipo,
                    Salida = b1.Salida,
                    Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                    Cantidad = b1.Cantidad / 2
                }
```

Conclusión 3:

La asignación de datos se estaba haciendo mal, ya que es diferente b1.fecha a b1.Fecha. Se debía poner en mayúscula la letra inicial.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas, veamos un ejemplo:

Crearé 3 clases "iguales", todas con una propiedad nombre:

```
public class Clase1
{
    public string Nombre { get; set;}
}
public class Clase2
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
public class Clase3
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Luego creo 2 funciones que me retornan una lista de `Clase1` y `Clase2`. Ambas listas tienen 2 elementos, con Nombre son `A` y `B` en ambas listas

```
public static List<Clase1> GetClases1() => [new Clase1() { Nombre = "A" }, new Clase1() { Nombre = "B" }];
public static List<Clase2> GetClases2() => [new Clase2() { Nombre = "A" }, new Clase2() { Nombre = "B" }];
```

Y más tarde simulo lo que tu estas haciendo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da el mismo error que tu tienes, porque `GetClases2` es una función, hay que utilizar los paréntesis!! así `GetClases2()`, por lo que sospecho que `GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros` es una función y debería ser:

```
//                      paréntesis  ----v   
join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros() on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
```

Pero tu problema no termina ahí, tu estas comparando 2 objetos derivados de una clase (cuando haces `equals`) y 2 objetos son iguales cuando comparten el mismo espació en memoria, **NO** cuando tienen los mismos valores en sus propiedades

Entonces si yo hago esto:

```
var query = from a in clases1
            join b in GetClases2() on new Clase3
            {
                Nombre = a.Nombre
            }
            equals new Clase3
            {
                Nombre = b.Nombre,
            }   
            into G
            select G;

    foreach(var grupo in query)
    {
        foreach(var item in grupo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Nombre);
        }
    }
```

No va imprimir nada, porque no realizo ningún join, la solución es cambiar `Clase3` de `class` a `record` (`TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros` en tu caso). Ya que los `record` si comparan 2 objetos por los valores de las propiedades

```
public record Clase3
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Y con esto, el código anterior imprime:

```
A
B
```

Que es lo que se espera.

Luego tienes otros elementos que me levantan sospechas, pero como no conozco el transfundo no puedo asegurarlo, pero por lo que veo me parece que esos `join` sobran, y que básicamente tu consulta es lo mismo que

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
public IEnumerable<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes,string? Obra, string? Almacen)
{
    var isObra = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Obra);
    var isBodega = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Obra);
    var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
    var q = from a in t
            where (isObra || Obra == a.Obra) && (isBodega || Almacen == a.nom_bodega)
            orderby
                a.Obra,
                a.equipo,
                a.fecha
            select a;
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Hola Yussef, gracias por la información. Según recomendación agregue los paréntesis y los debidos parámetros dentro de ellos. También cambie TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros  de class a record. A pesar de ello, me salio el error CS1061 en cinco oportunidades. Uno de ellas es esta: 
Error CS1061 'TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros' does not contain a definition for 'fecha' and no accessible extension method 'fecha' accepting a first argument of type 'TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Agradecemos observaciones.

Comment: Tendría que ver el código completo de las clases y las funciones