# Join de clave compuesta, no me entrega datos

Tags: c#, linq

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estoy utilizando un join del tipo combinación de clave compuesta para validar si en una lista ya existen registro que cumplan con dicha combinación.
Este es el código:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
    public List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes, 
        string? Obra, string? Almacen) 
    {
        var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
        var q = from a in t
                where
                (
                    (
                        Obra == null
                        ||
                        Obra == ""
                        ||
                        Obra == a.Obra
                    )
                    &&
                    (
                        Almacen == null
                        ||
                        Almacen == ""
                        ||
                        Almacen == a.nom_bodega
                    )
                )
                //join con la tabla obtenida en GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = a.fecha,
                    Equipo = a.equipo,
                    Salida = a.numero,
                    Bodega = a.bodega,
                    Cantidad = a.cantidad
                }
                equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.Equipo,
                    Salida = b1.Salida,
                    Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                    Cantidad = b1.Cantidad 
                }
                into GrupoB
                //esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby
                    a.Obra,
                    a.equipo,
                    a.fecha
                select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                {
                    equipo = a.equipo,
                    bodega = a.bodega,
                    nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                    cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                    familia = a.familia,
                    fecha = a.fecha,
                    codigo = a.codigo,
                    descripcion = a.descripcion,
                    tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                    tipo = a.tipo,
                    numero = a.numero,
                    cantidad = a.cantidad,
                    costo = a.costo,
                    total_costo = a.total_costo,
                    destino = a.destino,
                    horometro = a.horometro,
                    adicional = a.adicional,
                    horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                    empresa = a.empresa,
                    Obra = a.Obra,
                    //2024-02-01: Función que define el tipo de llanta que se esta montando.
                    Operacion = FuntionLlantaEstadoMontaje(a.codigo, a.descripcion),
                    //2024-01-29: Utilizamos el operador condicional ternario para definir el indicando
                    //si ya fue insertada la información.
                    Estado = b == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                };
        return q.ToList();
```

Al ejecutar el código, me pareció anormal que todos los registros salieran con el campo llamado Estado como "Pendiente". Por lo cual, valide los datos que tienen las listas que estamos comparando. Para ello, tome como ejemplo un registro en ambas listas y obtuve estos resultados:

```
Lista GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes)
{
    "equipo": "VD-363",
    "bodega": 1203,
    "nom_bodega": "ALMACEN PRINCIPAL MAGDALENA 2",
    "cod_familia": 1172,
    "familia": "RODAJE",
    "fecha": "2023-07-01T00:00:00",
    "codigo": "332569",
    "descripcion": "LLANTA 12R22.5 RADIAL DIRECCION  KMA01 KUMHO",
    "tipo_salida": "SA",
    "tipo": "SIMG",
    "numero": 108997,
    "cantidad": 2,
    "costo": 2089932.56,
    "total_costo": 4179865.12,
    "destino": "2.001.1087",
    "horometro": " 18883",
    "adicional": "h 18883/ kilometraje 1528  \nAlmacenista: / 121394, 121402",
    "horometro_ingresado": "18883.00",
    "empresa": "Construcciones el Condor S.A.",
    "obra": "MAGDALENA 2"
}

Lista GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes)
{
    "fecha": "2023-07-01T00:00:00",
    "equipo": "VD-363",
    "salida": 108997,
    "bodega": 1203,
    "cantidad": 2
}
```

Procedí a validar uno a uno los campos fecha, equipo, salida, bodega, cantidad. Encontré que eran iguales.

Luego pensé que el campo cantidad en una lista era de un tipo y en la otra lista era de otro tipo, pero recordé que para evitar esta situación, le definí el mismo tipo de datos a ambas lista, colocando el tipo TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros asi:

```
join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = a.fecha,
                    Equipo = a.equipo,
                    Salida = a.numero,
                    Bodega = a.bodega,
                    Cantidad = a.cantidad
                }
                equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                {
                    Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                    Equipo = b1.Equipo,
                    Salida = b1.Salida,
                    Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                    Cantidad = b1.Cantidad 
                }
                into GrupoB
```

Hasta el momento, continuo sin identificar la situación que hace parecer que en la lista b, no se tienen registro que cumplan con la clave combinada. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que esto se debe a lo que te dije en mi otra respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/612325/301324  (analiza lo que te digo en la segunda mitad de ella)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradecemos a Yussef por sus comentarios. Para que la condición ternaria funcionara correctamente, fue necesario cambiar la estructura de tipo TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros de class a record, quedando así:

```
public record TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? Equipo { get; set; }
    public int Salida { get; set; }
    public int Bodega { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Yussef nos compartío la causa:

> Tu estas comparando 2 objetos derivados de una clase (cuando haces
> equals) y 2 objetos son iguales cuando comparten el mismo espació en
> memoria, NO cuando tienen los mismos valores en sus propiedades. No va
> imprimir nada, porque no realizo ningún join, la solución es cambiar
> Clase3 de class a record (TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros en tu caso).
> Ya que los record si comparan 2 objetos por los valores de las
> propiedades